# Custom JAXB Bindings

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I've got an XML document which has the structure below.  ReportRaw represents the hex value of ReportConverted.  When I apply JAXB binding to this I will get a custom complex object representing ReportId with two child objects for ReportRaw and ReportConverted.

```
<Report>
    <ReportId>
        <ReportRaw>FA3</ReportRaw>
        <ReportConverted>4003</ReportConverted>
    </ReportId>
</Report>
```

My application doesn't use the ReportedRaw value so I'd like to simplify my generated object model and generate ReportId as an integer on the Report Object.  How can I go about doing this with jaxb custom bindings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the element `ReportRaw` either during marshal or unmarshall  then you can annotate with `@XmlTransient`.

And to do this using `jaxb` bindings, you will need to use [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin). Below is the usage.

```
 <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='ReportRaw']" >              
       <annox:annotate target="field">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient</annox:annotate>
   </jaxb:bindings>
```